# How to get cosine similarity value for words from two different lists in python

Tags: python, nlp, cosine-similarity

I have two lists of words as below

List1 = [apple, samsung, nokia, LG, micromax]

List2 = [Panasonic, nokia, Micromax, onida]

I want to get a cosine similarity value for each pair

e.g

(apple - nokia) 0.003

(nokia - nokia) 1.0

How do I accomplish this ?

Comment: With two "corpusses" the cosine similarity is quite meaningless: here it can take exactly three values: `0`, `1` and `0.707`. The idea of obtaining the similarity through corpusses in a "bag of words" style is that you need a huge set of corpusses, such that it becomes clear how related two concepts are. In this case apple-nokia would yield 0, and nokia-nokia 1.

Comment: I agree @WillemVanOnsem . Here is what i am trying to accomplish. I have list1 with 5 words. List2 with approx 3000 words. I want to create a third list List3 which has at most 5 most similar words (based on cosine similarity or any similarity measure) between the List1 and List2.

Comment: But here your answer will be strongly biased towards "coincidence". Imagine that you here have two articles, both talk about Apple computers, then Apple will be related to Nokia, Samsung, etc., but not towards pears, bananas, apple juice, whereas if you have a huge set, it will relate to both. The opposite can also happen. Typically statistical tools are only useful for a population that is large enough.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  In my case the list2 of 3000 words is  the single source of truth or say it is the world to us. We understand everything based on List2 words only. List1 will always have 5 words only. The reason to ask for cosine similarity is bcos, sometimes none of the words in List1 will match in List2.  But we don't want to show an empty hand. Instead we would be happy settling for a score of 0.2 between nokia - apple even if we know they are two different words and has no similarity.